# Cancan user update self if not admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am having trouble with cancan not allowing users to update their own data.

I am using the standard devise user controller which has the following code to check if the update is allowed with the following code:

```
def update
    authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      self.update_districts
      self.update_property_types
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
end
```

And here is my modified cancan ability code to allow the user to update their own model if they aren't an admin.

```
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :manage, User, :id => user.id
    end
```

Any ideas why this is not allowing me to update my own user data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing these 2 lines in the wrong order!

```
authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

In the `authorize!` line `@user` is just `nil`, so it's getting upset. Switch them around and it should work.  I.e.

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
```